# All links are getting redirected

Tags: redirect, directory, http-status-code-404

I'm having a very weird problem on my website. EVERY link to another html page is getting redirected to a 404 page because the directory is messed up.

For instance my website is www.mywebsite.com/en (note it's not at the root directory, it's in the "en" folder of root directory). If I have a link:

```
<a href="../site/page2.html">Link</a>
```

Instead of going to www.mywebsite.com/site/page2.html, it'll go to "http://www.mywebsite.com/**home/username/public_html/** site/page2/", which obviously doesn't exist. Why is it getting redirected to the "/home/username/public_html"?

This error does not occur in the local version when I test the webpage. It only happens after I upload it to the host (Hostgator).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. I guess you're using apache, so I would check url mapping.

Probably it has something to do with mod_userdir: [Mapping URLs to Filesystem Locations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html)